# Unable to create the application version in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a node-based application in beanstalk (I have done so successfully before), but every time I try to upload the zip file I get an error simply saying "Unable to create the application version." I know this alone is not very helpful, but it's literally all AWS is giving me - would anyone know how to troubleshoot this further to find possible causes?

Comment: SSH to the EB instance and check for any logs in /var/logs

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem.  It ended up being an issue with the latest version of Firefox (96.0.2 released on Jan. 20).  Once I switched browsers to Chrome, I was able to upload new application versions fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solved the problem for me